# SQL Sum not returning the correct data

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp-classic, openedge, progress-db

An example of my Progress database, opdetail table

```
invoice  invline    article   size    qty
----------------------------------------
905155   1          Shoe      10      5
905155   2          Slipper   3       2
905155   2          Slipper   4       6
905155   2          Slipper   5       1
905156   1          Boot      10      1 
905156   1          Boot      11      1
905157   1          Slipper   5       4       
905157   2          Shoe      8       6
```

a simple SQL select statement, run from the OpenEdge editor returns just what I need, a list of invoices with their total quantities:-

```
SELECT invoice, sum(qty) FROM opdetail GROUP BY qty ORDER BY invoice ASC
```

```
905155  14
905156   2
905157  10
```

HOWEVER:-
When run from an ASP page via DSN I have to list both fields in the GROUP BY otherwise progress returns a GROUP BY error

```
SELECT invoice, sum(qty) FROM opdetail GROUP BY qty, invoice ORDER BY invoice ASC
```

```
905155   5
905155   9
905156   2 
905157   4
905157   6
```

Its not summarizing the qty, and seems to be taking into account the line number even though the line number plays no part in my sql statement. Can anyone throw any light on this or how I can do a sum of the total qty taking into account the line number? Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate why you have to list both fields in the `group by`?  Are you sure it's Postgres complaining about that?

Comment: Yes, progress wanted all selected fields listing in the GROUP BY, but it appears that it doesn't mean summarised fields, so now its working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You are using `qty` in the aggregate function and then using on the `group by` this makes no sense and you should `group by` on some other column something as

```
SELECT 
invoice, 
sum(qty) FROM opdetail 
GROUP BY invoice ORDER BY invoice ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, solved ! The error message I was getting was ambiguous and suggested that qty should be included in the GROUP BY, but it wasn't the case, I had to include all selected fields in the GROUP except the summarised field!